# Responsive css to display mobile version of the webpage

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm working on a web page to show responsive version of the page on a mobile phone

when I resize the browser window in PC it displays just fine but when I open up the page from mobile phone, it just displays the whole page instead of the more simple mobile version as it does on the pc upon resizing

I'm not using any media or meta tag. I'm just using values in percentages..

Any suggestions if I should be using media or meta or viewport or something similar to control the mobile view as well?

Comment: hi user@Junaid Ali if your web sire Belongs to html/java/php use Adobe DreamWever it will work fine in all devices with in short time..

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to insert this metatag, otherwise it will show you the entire page.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

[Here you can read about this meta tag](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/mobifying/#toc-meta-viewport)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

You should use media queries. This will work regardless.

A quick example is:

```
.banner {
    width:1024px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:420px) {
    .banner {
        width:420px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the viewport meta tag and use media queries. 
Giving %'s to an element makes the element scalable, this doesn't mean a browser on a mobile phone knows it has to downscale. This is handled with media queries.

CSS-tricks is a nice website to learn and read more about media queries: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/ 
I recommend reading about it first, then try it, if you can't get it to work... well post it on Stack ^.^

Is this a sufficient answer for you?

Goodluck!

Comment: I find this answer the most precise and relevant to my problem :)

I will try this and let ya know if it worked for me or not (y)

Comment: Aye, goodluck mate. And if you need anymore help, don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: the issue is appearantly related to the viewport meta tag but I dont have access or permission to modify the html for the webpage.
Instead I've found that I can use @viewport in css for the same purpose but I'm unable to make it to show output

Comment: If I'm right, the viewport meta tag enables the media queries. If it works the same in CSS with `@viewport` too, try to make 1 element (like <nav>) downscalable by adjusting it's dimensions within the `@viewport` tag.

Comment: it was all fixed with the meta tag :)
I had the site admin to add the tag to the HTML and all the code worked perfect afterwards :)

Thanks a lot bro :)

Answer (score 0):

A per the Response Layout i Don't which technology and scripting you have used (`java,.net,php`)

for the Part of Meta check [this](http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/)

and also check this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=yes">
```

But If you Use `Adobe Dream Weaver` It will adjust the Response according to the Device.

and if you are using android Mobile Please check weather your Browser is in which mode (moile or Desktop). If its in Desktop change it to Mobile